# Trying to gather VPC subnet facts for an instance in AWS is showing error

Tags: ansible

```
fatal: [ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": null, 
            "aws_secret_key": null, 
            "ec2_url": null, 
            "filters": {
                "region": "us-east-1", 
                "vpc-id": "xxxxxxxxx"
            }, 
            "profile": null, 
            "region": null, 
            "security_token": null, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "region must be specified"
}
```

I am getting this aforementioned error from quite sometime while I am trying to gather details about VPC subnet facts from a particular instance in AWS. Can anyone please help if I am doing something wrong ? I have gone through the ansible doc on the same and based on the knowledge created this YML.

My YML file looks like :

```
---
 - name: find vpc facts
   hosts: webservers
   gather_facts: True
   tasks:
    - name: vpc subnet facts
      ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
       filters:
         region: us-east-1
         vpc-id: xxxxxxxx
      register: subnet_facts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> region must be specified

When calling ec2 modules, you should specify region as module parameter:

```
- name: vpc subnet facts
  ec2_vpc_subnet_facts:
    region: us-east-1
    filters:
      vpc-id: xxxxxxxx
  register: subnet_facts
```